# findViewById return null in onTabSelected function when using ActionBar

Tags: android

I use ActionBar.TabListener in my work. There are 4 tabs, and each tab has their own fragment. When I want to change the tab by OnTabSelected function, I try to find a tablelayout in the fragment for dynamic adding tablerows. But It returns null excetion.  After searching a lot of articles here, I thought the reason is that I find the id in the old fragment layout.  Should waiting for the current fragment is ready. (like onFinishinflate() ?)  Could anyone tell my how to figure it out?? Thanks a lot!

Here is my code

```
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction{
       mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition()); 
       if (tab.getPosition() == 0){
              TableLayout table = (TableLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.TableLayout1);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using

```
this.findViewById
```

use

```
getActivity().findViewById
```

or create a variable that stores the Context in the beginning:

```
Context context = this;
```

and then use

```
context.findViewById
```

Comment: Dear Cohen, Thank you for your replying, But my project extends FragmentActivity, which donen't have getActivity.  And the second method still return null.